# TPMS sensor issue after work performed

Tags: tire-pressure-monitoring-system

Last week I had purchased 4 new tires, new brakes, new battery at my local Firestone dealer all on the same visit. After the work was done I drove back home. When I started up the car the next day, my low tire pressure light was on. I immediately took it back to the Firestone dealer. They told me that I needed to replace 2 TPMS Sensors because the TPMS batteries were not working. Is this a coincidence or did they do something to hurt these sensors while installing my new tires and brakes and car battery? The cost for replacing these sensors was $159.98. I never had problems with my low tire pressure light going on since I purchased the car. It is a 2010 Ford Escape XLT.

Comment: Have you tried a manual reset?

Comment: It's easy to damage TPMS modules during tire dismount/mount and it would not surprise me if the tire shop messed them up.  Most TPMS modules have rebuild kits that include new batteries and sealing rings and that should have been a part of your tire change unless you specifically declined that service.  Usually it's $15-$20 a tire for parts and labor.  In your case it sounds like they replaced them entirely.

Comment: Typical TPMS battery life is 7-10 years, so you're due. The shop should have told you that when changing your tires. Those older sensors are easily damaged and it's not the shops fault in most cases. It's dissimilar metals used int he valve stem that causes corrosion.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The dealer did say they tried a manual reset. I got the complete brake job....new rotors pads etc. I never declined anything. That's probably why I spent almost 1500 that day. It just upsets me when after spending all that money and driving my car less than 15 miles total, I now have another $160.00 cost.

Comment: @user9181 Your comment should be an answer.